# Setting button.frame.origin does not change the location in scrollView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, scrollview

I'm adding a few buttons programmatically in a vertical ScrollView in swift. For each button, I calculate the room in the same row. If the room is enough, the button is added after the previous button, otherwise it will be added to a new row. I try to set the location of each button using

```
topButtons[j].frame.origin.x = currentOriginX
topButtons[j].frame.origin.y = currentOriginY
```

where currentOriginX and currentOriginY changes in each iteration. However, the buttons still appear at the top left corner of the scroll view and thus overlap each other. How do I solve this problem? (Also I wanted to keep the button width same as its text, so I didn't set the width of the button.)

My code is attached below.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var topScrollView: UIScrollView!
    var topButtons = [UIButtons()]
    func displayTopItems() {

        let scrollViewWidth = topScrollView.frame.size.width
        let buttonHeight = CGFloat(40)
        var currentOriginX = topScrollView.frame.origin.x
        var currentOriginY = topScrollView.frame.origin.y
        self.topScrollView.automaticallyAdjustsScrollIndicatorInsets = false
        self.topScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        self.topScrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.topScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        for j in 0..<self.itemsClass.toBuyItems.count {

            topButtons.append(UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system))
            topButtons[j].setTitle(self.itemsClass.toBuyItems[j], for: UIControl.State.normal)

            let buttonWidth = topButtons[j].frame.size.width
            if j > 0 {
                let lastButtonLeft = topButtons[j-1].frame.origin.x
                let lastButtonWidth = topButtons[j-1].frame.size.width
                let sameRow = lastButtonLeft + lastButtonWidth + buttonWidth + 50 < scrollViewWidth
                if sameRow {
                    currentOriginX += lastButtonWidth + 30
                }
                else {
                    currentOriginX = 0
                    currentOriginY += buttonSize.height + 20
                }
            }
//            self.topScrollView.contentOffset.x = currentOriginX
//            self.topScrollView.contentOffset.y = currentOriginY
            topButtons[j].frame.origin.x = currentOriginX
            topButtons[j].frame.origin.y = currentOriginY
            topButtons[j].setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            topButtons[j].backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            topButtons[j].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            topButtons[j].heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonSize.height).isActive = true
            topButtons[j].layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            topButtons[j].layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
            topButtons[j].addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
            topButtons[j].tag = j
            self.topScrollView.addSubview(topButtons[j])
        }
    }
```

Comment: `var currentOriginX = topScrollView.frame.origin.x` should be `var currentOriginX = topScrollView.bounds.origin.x`, no? Same for `currentOriginY`.

Comment: Changing that had no effect...

Comment: You are mixing explicit frames and auto-layout / constraints, which generally causes issues. You have this line: `let buttonSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 40)` ... does that mean you want all buttons to be `200 x 40`? Or do you want them to be 40-pts tall but fit the widths to the titles?

Answer (score 0):

The location of buttons need to be set by specifying the constraints after they are added to a view.

```
    topButtons[j].setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    topButtons[j].backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    topButtons[j].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    topButtons[j].heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonSize.height).isActive = true
    topButtons[j].layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    topButtons[j].layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    topButtons[j].addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    topButtons[j].tag = j
    self.topScrollView.addSubview(topButtons[j])
    // do this after adding buttons to view
    topButtons[j].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topScrollView.topAnchor, constant: currentOriginY).isActive = true
    topButtons[j].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: currentOriginX).isActive = true
```